# Import GA4 data

Tags: import

tell me if there is an api for getting ga4 resources, in particular an api for importing data? The documentation describes api for UA, but the methods given do not even return a list of GA4 resources, and there is nothing about GA4 at all

Automate data loading

Answer (score 0):

See GA [Analytics Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is nothing related in the data loading api in GA4

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python then using this code you can extract data using GA4 API. Here you can specify which dimensions and metrics you needed and apply date_ranges and filters. finally save as csv or parquet file as you needed.

```
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    MetricType,
    RunReportRequest,
)
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import os
import csv

def run_sample():
    """Runs the sample."""
    # TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
    #  property ID before running the sample.
    property_id = "property_id"
    run_report(property_id)


def run_report(property_id="YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"):
    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        dimensions=[Dimension(name="region"),Dimension(name="sessionSourceMedium"),Dimension(name="sessionSource"),Dimension(name="date"),Dimension(name="transactionId") ],
        metrics=[Metric(name="transactions"),Metric(name="eventCount")],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-06-16", end_date="2023-06-30")],
    )
    response = client.run_report(request)
    # print_run_report_response(response)
    query_data(response)

def query_data(api_response):
    dimension_headers = [header.name for header in api_response.dimension_headers]
    metric_headers = [header.name for header in api_response.metric_headers]
    dimensions = []
    metrics = []
    for i in range(len(dimension_headers)):
        dimensions.append([row.dimension_values[i].value for row in api_response.rows])
    dimensions
    for i in range(len(metric_headers)):
        metrics.append([row.metric_values[i].value for row in api_response.rows])
    headers = dimension_headers, metric_headers
    headers = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(headers))   
    data = dimensions, metrics
    data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.transpose()
    df.columns = headers
    df.to_csv("Test.csv", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```